# Why does React SSR Online Store crash when updating a product page?

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, server-side-rendering

When you click on a product, initially the component with the product page is normally shown in all the data about the product, but after updating this page everything disappears and in DevTools on the Network there is no request for product.json, the product data is taken from there. How can I solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riZ53.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNcr.png)

And after refreshing the page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2OMV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU0i6.png)

I passed the ID to the page component and the data was supposed to be taken from the product json, but when updating the page there was a problem

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve your question by including relevant code snippets. For anyone to propose a solution, code snippets are necessary